# Mute speaker in action script

Tags: apache-flex, flash, actionscript-3, mxml, mxmlc

In the following code how to mute the speakers

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<mx:Application
xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml"
layout="absolute"
width="300"
height="100"
creationComplete="init()">

<mx:Script>
<![CDATA[
 import mx.controls.Alert;
 import mx.media.*;
 import flash.net.NetStream;

 private var myMic:Microphone;
 private var recordingState:String = "idle";

 private function init():void {

    myMic = Microphone.getMicrophone();
    myMic.setSilenceLevel(0);
    myMic.rate = 44;
    myMic.gain = 100;
    myMic.setUseEchoSuppression(true);
    micLevel.visible = true;
    //Security.showSettings(SecurityPanel.MICROPHONE);
    myMic.setLoopBack(true);
    if (myMic != null)
    {
       myMic.setUseEchoSuppression(true);
       micLevel.setProgress(myMic.activityLevel, 100);
       addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, showMicLevel);
       //micLevel.setProgress(myMic.activityLevel, 100);
    }

 }

 private function showMicLevel(event:Event):void{
    switch (recordingState){
       case "idle" :
          micLevel.setProgress(myMic.activityLevel, 100);
          break;
    }

   }







 ]]>
 </mx:Script>

<mx:ProgressBar x="0" y="36" mode="manual" id="micLevel" label="" labelPlacement="bottom" width="100" fontSize="10" fontWeight="normal"/>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just want to disble the voice from microphone to come into the speakers do

```
myMic.setLoopBack(false);
```

This will disable the sound detected by microphone to be played in the speakers.

EDIT1:

```
//use the function to disable sound completely.


 private function disableSound():void
 {
    var newSoundTransform:SoundTransform=new SoundTransform();
    newSoundTransform.volume=0;
    this.soundTransform=newSoundTransform;
}
```

Call the above function in init() function.
This will completely disable all sounds coming from the application.

Comment: Actually when i increase the volume on the system it just reproduces some unwanted noise so trying to get rid of it..

Comment: if you want to completely disable sound for your application, then you can simply use a soundTransform object on the application.Ill edit my answer with the required changes shortly.

Comment: I 2 found a fix but not so sure of it,in the above code itself Mymic.gain *= 0.8; seems like it solved my problem.Is this a valid fix? Also how will i change the bar color in the above code

Comment: Rajeev, the fix if working seems to be a good way to do it.Also to change the colour use <mx:ProgressBar color="0xFF0000" the colour is in the form 0XRRGGBB

Comment: Are you sure about it the flex compiler had given me some error i tried it days ago

Comment: im sorry to change the colour of the progress bar you need <mx:ProgressBar chromeColor="#F62626"/>.Please try this out.This will surely work

Comment: That worked but even the background color changed ?Can we not retain the background color and change only the bar color

Comment: try using labelPlacement="bottom" , that would actully reduce the size of the progressbar and you would see two seperate colous for the progressbar and the label.

Comment: And neeraj is there a way to disable the security question that is been asked when the microphone  is accessed Allow/Deny..

Comment: I checked a few places, it doesnt seem possible, the reason is that, the browser doesn't allow any webapp to directly access low level resources like webcam data, without users permission.

Comment: Thanks for all the help Neeraj.Appreciate it